# Integrating Markitup with Django: No module markup

Tags: python, django, markup

I am trying to use django-markitup for textareas in a django 1.6 project with wiki syntax. But it is giving following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not import MARKITUP_FILTER ('django.contrib.markup.templatetags.markup.wiki', {}): No module named markup.templatetags.markup
```

I copied wiki set to python dist-packages - markitup directory, as by default markitup doesn't come with wiki set. I am getting toolbar of wiki syntax, but markup to HTML conversion is not happening properly because of above mentioned error.

After searching on google, I came to know that markup module is deprecated in django 1.5 and is removed from django 1.6

Then how to configure wiki syntax in django-markitup?

Comment: I think you answered your own question: _"markup module is deprecated in django 1.5 and is removed from 1.6"_ since its removed, you need to find another module to provide you the same features.

Comment: escapee use **pip install docutils**

Comment: I used docutils but it can be used for restructuredtext and textile sets, and not for wiki

Answer (score 0):

Someone made a drop-in replacement for django's old markup module (they basically just took a snapshot of it at v1.4 and uploaded it to pypi). Just install it and your old app should work without modification.

https://github.com/Alir3z4/django-markwhat

```
pip install django-markwhat
```